Amount Transfer Between Different Accounts - Improved Version
This is an improved code version for Amount Transfer Between Different Accounts
Welcoming any further improvements for this.
  import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
  import java.math.BigDecimal;
  import java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock;
  import static com.java.learning.bankaccount.Constants.*;

 public class BankAccount {

 private BigDecimal balance;
 private final Long accountNumber;
 private final AccountType accountType;
 private final AccountStatus status;
 private final StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();

 BankAccount(@NotNull(message = ILLEGAL_ACCOUNT) Long accountNumber,
             AccountType accountType) {
     balance = BigDecimal.valueOf(0L);
     this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
     this.accountType = accountType != null ? accountType : AccountType.SAVINGS;
     this.status = AccountStatus.CREATED;
     AccountRepository.addAccount(accountNumber,this);
 }

 public void deposit(BigDecimal amount) {
     long stamp = lock.tryWriteLock();
     if (lock.validate(stamp)) {
         try {
             stamp = lock.writeLock();
             validateStatus();
             balance = balance.add(amount);
         } finally {
             lock.unlockWrite(stamp);
         }
     }
 }

 public void withdraw(BigDecimal amount)
 {
     long stamp = lock.tryWriteLock();
     if (lock.validate(stamp)) {
         try {
             stamp = lock.writeLock();
             validateStatus();
             validateBalance(amount);
             balance = balance.subtract(amount);
         } finally {
             lock.unlockWrite(stamp);
         }
     }
 }

 public void validateStatus() {
     if (status != AccountStatus.ACTIVATED) {
         throw new BankAccountGeneralException(ACCOUNT_STATUS_INVALID);
     }
 }

 private void validateBalance(BigDecimal amount) {
     if (balance.compareTo(amount) < 0) {
         throw new BankAccountGeneralException(INSUFFICIENT_BALANCE);
     }
 }

 }




import java.math.BigDecimal;

public interface IAccountService {

BankAccount findAccountById(Long accountNumber);

void transfer(BigDecimal amount, Long fromAccountNumber, Long toAccountNumber);

}
  

   
  
  import jakarta.validation.constraints.DecimalMin;
  import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

  import javax.annotation.Resource;
  import java.math.BigDecimal;

  import static com.java.learning.bankaccount.Constants.*;

  @Resource
  public class AccountService implements IAccountService {

  @Override
  public BankAccount findAccountById(@NotNull(message = ILLEGAL_ACCOUNT) Long  
                                     accountNumber) {
      BankAccount bankAccount = AccountRepository.getAccountMap().get(accountNumber);
      if (bankAccount == null) {
          throw new BankAccountGeneralException(ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND);
      }
      return bankAccount;
  }

  @Override
  public void transfer(@NotNull(message = INVALID_TRANSACTION) @DecimalMin(value = 
                       "0.01", message = INVALID_TRANSACTION)
                       BigDecimal amount, @NotNull(message = ILLEGAL_ACCOUNT) Long 
                       fromAccountNumber,
                       @NotNull(message = ILLEGAL_ACCOUNT) Long toAccountNumber) {

      if (fromAccountNumber.equals(toAccountNumber)) {
          throw new BankAccountGeneralException(SELF_TRANSFER_DISABLED);
      }
      BankAccount fromAccount = findAccountById(fromAccountNumber);
      BankAccount toAccount = findAccountById(toAccountNumber);
      fromAccount.withdraw(amount);
      toAccount.deposit(amount);
  }
  } 


 import java.util.Map;
 import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

 public final class AccountRepository {

 private static final Map<Long, BankAccount> accountMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

 private AccountRepository() {
    // private empty constructor
 }

 public static void addAccount(Long accountNumber, BankAccount bankAccount) {
    accountMap.putIfAbsent(accountNumber, bankAccount);
 }

 public static Map<Long, BankAccount> getAccountMap() {
    return accountMap;
 }
 }

    public enum AccountStatus {
     CREATED, ACTIVATED, CLOSED;
    }


 public enum AccountType {
  SAVINGS, CURRENT;
 }

   public final class Constants {

    private Constants()
   {
       //empty private constructor
   }

   public static final String ILLEGAL_ACCOUNT = "Illegal Account Number";
   public static final String ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND = "Bank Account Not Found";
   public static final String SELF_TRANSFER_DISABLED = "Self Transfer Not Allowed";
   public static final String INVALID_TRANSACTION = "Invalid Transaction Amount";
   public static final String ACCOUNT_STATUS_INVALID = "Account Not Active";
   public static final String INSUFFICIENT_BALANCE = "Insufficient Account Balance";


   }


public class BankAccountGeneralException extends RuntimeException {

public BankAccountGeneralException(String errorMessage) {
    super(errorMessage);
}

}


Can you, please, fix the issue with formatting? (since it wasn't mentioned in the answer, you're free to it). It seems like you're using together so-called code fences ``` and Code Sample button {} which ruins your indentations.

If you have properly formatted class in your IDE - just copy it, and paste in between code fences ``` (without using Code Sample button {}).

Placing a @NotNull annotation on a Long value is pointless, since it can be replaced with a primitive long instead.

Overall, it looks better. BankAccount exposes domain-specific methods that clearly communicate the purpose of this class.
But there are still issues to address.
Concurrency
All methods representing transactions have bugs in them:

both withdraw() and deposit() either exit doing nothing or will block forever;

you didn't ensure that separate actions inside transfer() are executed atomically.


Additionally, I still don't see how you benefit from using StamptLock, it shines only when it comes to optimistic reading. If you used ReadWriteLock instead, the code will be a bit simpler since, there will be no need to validate stamps.
withdraw() / deposit()
In both methods, you're trying to acquire a write lock twice.
long stamp = lock.tryWriteLock();
    if (lock.validate(stamp)) {
        try {
            stamp = lock.writeLock();
            // ...

Execution can reach the line where you invoke lock.writeLock() (which is attempting to obtain lock blocking the thread, if not available) only if condition lock.validate(stamp) is evaluated to true. Which means that a write lock has already been acquired by the tryWriteLock().
Since StamptLock is not reentrant, the thread will block itself.
If your intention was to wait until the lock is available, then use writeLock().
Also, mind that, it's recommended specifying timeout instead of waiting indefinitely.
transfer() - lack of Atomicity
Withdraw and deposit are not executed atomically.
withdraw() and deposit() will run as two separate transactions.
What can go wrong?
Imagine a situation when withdraw operation succeeds while deposit fails. It might happen if the recipient account fails to acquire a write lock (that's a possible scenario since you're using non-blocking lock acquisition). Or it'll happen if the recipient account is not ACTIVATED for some reason.
To avoid this, both accounts should be locked before commencing withdraw() and unlocked after performing deposit().
Try to solve this issue without turning BankAccount into a bag of values, as it was before.
Leaky Abstraction
AccountRepository which is supposed to be a fake repository, leaks details of how it stores and retrieves accounts by exposing accountMap.
Additionally, this map is static and by means of static methods.
This should not happen.

Avoid using static mutable state, it's a bad habit

Make both the map of accounts and method addAccount() to be instance members of AccountRepository.

Don't break the encapsulation.

Ditch the getAccountMap() method.
Instead, expose findAccountById() method returning either BankAccount or Optional<BankAccount>.
This way, the internal mechanics of your fake repository will be abstracted away.
BankAccount
Let's play the game "Try to spot the issue", what's wrong with this constructor?
BankAccount(@NotNull(message = ILLEGAL_ACCOUNT) Long accountNumber,
            AccountType accountType) {
    balance = BigDecimal.valueOf(0L);
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.accountType = accountType != null ? accountType : AccountType.SAVINGS;
    this.status = AccountStatus.CREATED;
    AccountRepository.addAccount(accountNumber,this);
} 


First and foremost, we have a violation of the Single-responsibility principle (which is the S in SOLID).

This line should not belong to constructor (as well as to any member of BankAccount class):
AccountRepository.addAccount(accountNumber,this);

The only responsibility of the constructor is to produce a correctly instantiated instance of a type.
Avoid hacks with static methods and static state.

null should have no special meaning in your business logic.

this.accountType = accountType != null ? accountType : AccountType.SAVINGS;

Why null means AccountType.SAVINGS? It shouldn't be the case, avoid passing null values around and assigning special meanings to them.
You can define an overloaded constructor that doesn't expect  AccountType and a default account type which it will use (if that was your intention).

Why making this constructor package-private instead of public?

Constants
This bag of constants is not a good idea. Because exception messages you placed there bear no meaning in the context of this faceless class.
Instead, these messages should reside where they are used.

To avoid this, both accounts should be locked before commencing withdraw() and unlocked after performing deposit() ==> is there a better approach other than using synchronized(this) block ?

@Jill You can perform locking using either intrinsic locks (i.e. monitors used for synchronization) or explicit locks in the form of Lock and StampedLock. They both have the same semantics. You lock against an intrinsic monitor, but not with synchronized(this). Why? Ask yourself what this refers to in the service's instance method and what the implications will be. If two or more threads are trying to execute a block of code synchronized against the same monitor, only one will be allowed to enter; all others will be blocked. I hope that it's clear.

@Jill And in case of synchronized(this) any thread executing transfer() will block all other threads (even if intend to work with different accounts) because synchronization is done on an instance of service this. To avoid blocking threads that would not otherwise interfere, you should do something along these lines: synchronized(from) { synchronized(to) { *check balance and statuses* from.withdraw(); to.deposit(); } }. This should work. A more elegant solution can be achieved if you introduce methods boolean lock() and void unlock() in the BankAccount class.

@Jill And mind of what I said about StamptLock not being reentrant in both this and previous answer.

I am planning to add another improved version of the same question by adding all your recommendations. Stampedlock.tryWriteLock() vs ReEntrantReadWriteLock.writeLock().tryLock() , is the only difference in validating the stamp additionally for StampedLock?

have created a gist for the improved one ==> https://gist.github.com/akhilvsankar/47f1ef94b920f3b0c77e402f5295b49e.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
